# SwiftUI not loading JSON data even though JSON file is found

Tags: json, swift, decoding

I have a JSON file with some people in it :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Mandy",
        "summary": "This is a summary for person 1",
        "detail": "This is a detailed description for person 1",
        "category": "Leaders"
    },
```

it matches my person and category models :

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var summary: String
    var detail: String
    var category: Category
} 

enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case leaders = "Leaders"
    case competitors = "Competitors"
    case thinkers = "Thinkers"
    case explorers = "Explorers"
}
```

I have a dataloader to load the JSON into my project (loads some dummy data for when using preview) :

```
class DataLoader: ObservableObject {

@Published var people: [Person] = []

init(preview: Bool = false) {
    if preview {
        // For SwiftUI Preview
        people = [
            Person(name: "Preview Leader", summary: "Leader Summary", detail: "Detail about the Leader", category: .leaders),
            Person(name: "Preview Competitor", summary: "Competitor Summary", detail: "Detail about the Competitor", category: .competitors),
            Person(name: "Preview Thinker", summary: "Thinker Summary", detail: "Detail about the Thinker", category: .thinkers),
            Person(name: "Preview Explorer", summary: "Explorer Summary", detail: "Detail about the Explorer", category: .explorers)
        ]
    } else {
        // For Actual App Run
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "people", withExtension: "json") else {
            fatalError("Could not find file in bundle")
        }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            print("Data loaded successfully: \(data)")
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: data)
            self.people = decodedData
            print("Decoded data: \(decodedData)")
        } catch {
            print("Error while parsing: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

}

and then observed in my views like this ...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataLoader: DataLoader
    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View{.....
```

it doesn't trigger any errors, so the file is found. But it also doesn't print any of the print statements in the data loader - as if it's not parsing the JSON at all. Am I missing something here?

I also have this in my app.swift, which I tried from other answers here :

```
struct myApp: SwiftUI.App {
    @StateObject private var dataLoader = DataLoader(preview: false) // Set 'false' for the actual app.
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(dataLoader)
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I added this to my initialiser of the dataloader but nothing gets printed :

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
        if let path = bundle.path(forResource: "people", ofType: "json") {
            print("people.json file path: \(path)")
        } else {
            print("people.json file not found in bundle.")
        }
```

***Update 2***
Thanks to @soundflix comment, in Xcode’s debug console, I selected „All output“.
Now the error output is printing:

> Error while parsing: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
> "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
> "Badly formed object around line 4, column 8."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around line 4, column 8., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=36})))

however, a JSON validator online says my JSON is good

Comment: Maybe you don’t display print output?

Comment: In Xcode’s debug console, check if „All output“, and not „Debug output“ is selected.

Comment: thanks - have updated with the error from console

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Okay so I added this to my DataLoader to get more detail on the issue :

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {

 print(json)
                        }
```

I got this error :

```
Error while parsing: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

The JSON was looking for UUID that wasn't present in my JSON. I didn't want to add a UUID to every JSON entry so I used this :

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name, summary, detail, category
        }
```

to exclude UUID from the properties associated with JSON keys. The decoder will then go ahead and create a UUID for each JSON entry (which I don't need for now but might be useful in future)

hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: Seems like a handy debugging trick to use `JSONSerialization` to get detailed error that `JSONDecoder` doesn’t give.